# How can I plot the following function in MATLAB?

Tags: arrays, matlab, matlab-figure

How can I plot the following function in MATLAB?

```
x = 0:20:200;
y = 1+((x/8)^(1/3))+((8/x)^(1/3));`
```

I tried it using `plot(x,y)`, but it doesn't run any output. Any help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should change all operators that get `x` to [elements-wise](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/array-vs-matrix-operations.html). this is done by adding `.` before the operator. So `*` is matrix multiplication, while `.*` is an element by element multiplication. This is true also for `^` and `/`. `+` and `-` are always element-wise. For `.*` the two inputs must be the same size and shape, or one of them is a scalar. For `.^` and `./` it's better to always use them if you know that you are only dealing with array operations (unless both elements are scalars).

```
x = 0:20:200;
y = 1+((x./8).^(1/3))+((8./x).^(1/3));
plot(x,y)
```

[image: simple plot]